# Updadting snap "brave" Fetch and check assertions for snap "brave" (270) (cannot verify snap "brave", no matching signatures found)

Tags: snap, snap-store, brave

I'm getting this error when I try and update the brave snap how can this be fixed?

**error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Fetch and check assertions for snap "brave" (270) (cannot verify snap "brave", no matching signatures found)**

rt@sas:~$ uname -a
Linux sys76 5.15.0-83-generic #92~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 21 14:00:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
rt@sas:~$

```
List installed snaps

Name                                   Version                           Rev    Tracking         Publisher           Notes
brave                                  1.57.53                           268    latest/stable    brave✓     

     -

List available snap refresh

Name   Version  Rev  Size   Publisher  Notes
brave  1.57.57  270  165MB  brave✓     -
```